# Removing "/" symbol from a file shell

Tags: shell

I have this file

```
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/
/sauga/pratybos/SNMP.ppt
/
/
/
/
/
/
/
/
/favicon.ico
/
/
/
/
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/
/
/os/chap07_files/slide0018.htm
/
/
/
/
/
/
/
/
/
/
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/
/
/
http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com/
/
/
/
/
```

And I want to remove  `/` only if there are no text 
so my output should be

```
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/sauga/pratybos/SNMP.ppt
/favicon.ico
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/os/chap07_files/slide0018.htm
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com/
```

I can easily be done like this

```
awk '{gsub("/", "");print}' 1a.txt > a.txt
```

but then all `/` would be removed

Is it possible to do that in shell?

Comment: Note that the sample file content has Windows-style (`\r\n`) file endings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep -v` to select only lines that are not "/":

```
grep -v '^/$' 1a.txt > a.txt
```

Edit, thanks to Glenn Jackman comment!:
Simpler variant of this command with the `-x` option to match exactly the whole line like a `^`...`$` regular expression:

```
grep -vx / 1a.txt > a.txt
```

Comment: can be even simpler: `grep -vx /` -- "Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line."

Comment: @glennjackman you should turn grep -vx and your awk example below in an answer

Comment: @glennjackman you are right it's simpler with the `-x`option, i edit the answer with this variant, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This should return your desired output:

```
sed '/^\/$/d' infile > outfile
```

or:

```
sed -i.bak '/^\/$/d' infile
```

to edit it in-place while taking a backup copy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep -v`:

```
grep -Ev '^ */ *$' file
/sauga/pratybos/SNMP.ppt
/favicon.ico
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/os/chap07_files/slide0018.htm
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
http://www.google.com/
http://www.google.com/
```

If there are no spaced around `/` then use:

```
grep -vx '/' file
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk '!/ *\/ *$/' file
/sauga/pratybos/SNMP.ppt
/favicon.ico
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
/os/chap07_files/slide0018.htm
/sauga/pratybos/NAT.ppt
```

Comment: Don't need regex with awk: `awk '$1 != "/"'`

Comment: I used regex to allow leading and trailing spaces around `/`. If that's not the case then use shortest grep using : `grep -vx '/' file`

Comment: With awk's default FS, surrounding whitespace is taken care of.